# VIM + ctags open too many annoying buffers

Tags: vi, ctags

I usually only works on two or three files at one time, so after mapping "Shift+H" to ":bn", I can quickly switch among these files by pressing "shift+H" several times (I don't have to use :ls plus :bn). But after jumping to/back the definitions of functions via ctags's ctrl+], it opens many buffers for new files (:ls now shows many buffers).  Now as the number of opened buffers increases, it is slow to relocate to new files using "Shift+H"(:bn). Any ideas? Do you have these problems? Is it possible to hidden buffer caused by ctags or at least delete these ctags_caused buffers when code returning from jumping? Thanks.

PS: I don't like the way of using :ls to see the file you want to jump, then using:bn to switch files, since I think pressing "shift+H" is more convenient and faster.

Thanks.

---Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using vim then using tabs instead of buffers may solve the problem.

You can open the two or three files in separate tabs (:tabnew filename), and use the 'gT' and 'gt' normal commands to switch back and forth between the tabs.

You can modify your "shift+H" mapping to either 'gT' or 'gt'.

You can also use ctrl+w ctrl+] to jump to function definition in a new window so that you can close the new window and go back to your original window containing the buffer that you jumped from.

Also related, when I have many buffers loaded I normally rely on the ":b" command completion's feature to quickly switch to the buffer that I want based on the partial filename that I give to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions so quick! This is exactly what I have want. Awesome both you and vim!